# Connecting to SQLite DB over network

Tags: c#, sqlite, sqlconnection

I am currently mapping a network drive and connecting to the file (Z:\Data\Database.db) that way. I would like to be able to just use a relative path (\server\Data\Database.db) in the connection string but it is giving me a SQLite error "unable to open database file". A `Directory.Exists(\\server\Data\Database.db);` check is returning true.

Here is the attempt to open the connection using the path "\\server" as the argument:

```
public static OpenDB(string dbPath)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={Path.Combine(dbPath, "Data\\Database.db")}"))
    {
        if (dbPath != null && dbPath != "")
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable to Open Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The drive need to be shared and the network credentials must allow user to read file.

Comment: The folder and the file itself are set with full read/write permission for all users. The root folder ("Data") is a network shared drive.

Comment: Can you use windows explorer ti open using same path?  This will verify that the credentials are valid between machines.  It doesn't matter if file is read all if the user account is not valid on both machines.  There must be a group account to allow two PC to have same credentials.

Comment: That might be the issue. The file is accessible via windows explorer but each machine is logged in as the local admin account.

Comment: Try c$ see : https://superuser.com/questions/328461/how-to-access-c-share-in-a-network

Comment: Note that it's not recommended to host sqlite databases on network drives due to potential corruption problems.

Comment: @jdweng This worked really well. I'm using a combination of the administrative share and making a temp copy of the database file on the local machine to avoid the issues Shawn mentioned. Please write your comment as an answer so that I can give you credit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was the solution that I used. It is a combination of advice from [jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) and [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn). First I made the path `dbPath` be an administrative share drive. From there I made the program make a temporary local copy of the database from the administrative share:

```
private static void MakeTempDatabaseCopy(string dbPath, string exePath)
{
    try
    {
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(dbPath, "Data", "Database.db"), Path.Combine(exePath, "Temp", "Database.db"), true);
        FileInfo directoryInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(exePath, "Temp", "Database.db"));
        directoryInfo.Attributes = FileAttributes.Temporary;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Retrieving Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

After that all methods can read from the local copy. Since the `File.Copy()` uses the Boolean, anything that requires a refresh of the database can just overwrite the local copy with a fresh copy from the administrative share. Hope this helps!